Powershell -Mailbox switch isn't working correctly
I've got a bit of an issue with Exchange Online Management Module where it won't recognise the -Mailbox tag.
It used to work, and on the Learn page it is still listed as being a correct parameter.
Below is the code and then the error I get.
Function EXO-UserMailboxRules {
    #Pulls back list of mailbox rules and formats with Name, Description and Enabled status
    #Get the username
    $GetUsername = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username to check rules (you need to be connected to EXO first)"
    #Pull back list of rules based on Rule name, and select the name only
    $MailboxRuleList = get-InboxRule -Mailbox $GetUsername | select Name
    #Start Foreach loop. You can reference the Rule as a variable here, and then get it to pull one Name at a time as it goes
    foreach ($Rule in $MailboxRuleList) {
        $RuleName = $Rule.Name
        #Run Get-InboxRule again, this time on the rule name. Pull the Rule Name, Description, and if enabled
        get-inboxrule $RuleName -Mailbox $GetUsername | select Name, Description, Enabled | fl
    }
}

Get-InboxRule : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Mailbox'.
At C:\Scripts\ExchangeManagement.psm1:38 char:38
+     $MailboxRuleList = get-InboxRule -Mailbox $GetUsername | select N ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-InboxRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Get-InboxRule

I have tried finding another parameter to use, but the MS Learn page shows using the -Mailbox to pick out the mailbox.
I can't think of what to try in the first instance as I am connected to EXO and it was working before.

On second look, it appears you may be using a custom exchange module. It shows C:\Scripts\ExchangeManagement.psm1  Make sure you have the proper module installed and are using it.
